# Bitbucket pipline yml deployment with SSH throws error

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have followed all instructions from this link:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/

1. Generated new SSH key pairs
2. Added address to the known hosts with Fetch
3. Added Publick key to aothorized_keys on remote server
4. build the pipline

And when i run the pipeline i get this after i try to ssh to the remote server:

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

The complete log after ssh -v:

```
+ ssh -v $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug1: Connecting to $DEPLOY_HOST [$DEPLOY_HOST] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA c4:e0:d8:55:dc:6b:43
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed
```

What I am doing wrong in the whole process ?

Comment: i have exactly same issue

Comment: Did you find a solution ?